# Ghostery Add-On would not block this time?

Tags: blocking, ghostery

This is the first time it's ever happened, but I saw an unblocked tracker when accessing a site and when I clicked on the box to block it, I got a notice that Ghostery "only blocks sites beginning with http:// or https://".  I did see that the site I was on had nothing before the domain name.  I don't find anyway to override it, but I don't want to be tracked, either.  If I can't customize Ghostery to block regardless, can Firefox be customized to force http:// or https:// before every domain?  (I freely admit I know nothing about this stuff, therefore I ask.)  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Ah...  I installed the Firefox add-on [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) and, although I do not actually see "https://" before the domain, it still seems to have satisfied Ghostery.  It was grayed out before; now it seems fine.